# c++ returning reference actually returns garbage value

Tags: c++

I'm learning OpenGL with scarce C++ background. Please see below code snippet which I minimalized my problem as possible as I can:

```cpp
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

class TestObj
{
private:
    glm::mat4 t;

public:
    TestObj()
    {
        t = glm::mat4(1);
    }

    const glm::mat4& GetT()
    {
        return t;
    }

    const glm::vec3& GetPos()
    {
        return GetT()[3];
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    TestObj o;

    const auto& w1 = o.GetT()[3];
    const auto& w2 = o.GetPos();

    std::cout << "w1: " << w1.x << " " << w1.y << " " << w1.z << std::endl;
    std::cout << "w2: " << w2.x << " " << w2.y << " " << w2.z << "\n" << std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

As you can see, `GetT()[3]` and `GetPos()` are identically implemented, but running this code outputs:

```
w1: 0 0 0
w2: 4.59149e-41 1.4013e-45 0
```

`w2` from `GetPos()` returns garbage value.

*BUT*, when I changed the return type of `GetPos()` to `const glm::vec4&`, it worked fine without returning garbage value.

`operator[]` for `glm::mat4` returns `const glm::vec4&`, but of course there is implicit casting implemented from `glm::vec4` to `glm::vec3`, so there is no need to be error during casting.

Am I doing wrong? What's happening downside?

Comment: Your return temporary `glm::vec3` created from `const glm::vec4&`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm sorry, but would you please explain with more detail? I couldn't understand perfectly :(

Comment: `return GetT()[3];` is equivalent to `return glm::vec3{GetT()[3]};` so you return dangling pointer

Comment: `GetPos()` should not return a reference but an actual value.

Comment: *Binding* a temporary object to a const refererence (as in `const auto& w1 = o.GetT()[3];`) extends its lifetime; returning a reference to a temporary object doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, `GetT()[3]` is a `glm::vec4`, so it needs conversion to got `glm::vec3`.

So your code is mostly equivalent to

```
const glm::vec3& GetPos()
{
    const glm::vec4& vec4 = GetT()[3];
    glm::vec3 vec3{vec4}; // Conversion
    return vec3;
}
```

Returning dangling pointer.

Comment: Oh my, I couldn't notice it at all. I just thought that casting would just change the object  just like C#, which is my main language.

Comment: So either return `const glm::vec4&` or `glm::vec3` (no reference).